# Dotnet core application hosted on Linux not connecting to the SQL server that installed in Azure VM

Tags: sql-server, linux, azure, asp.net-core, virtual-machine

Angular + dotnet core application that hosted on the Linux server(centos) is throwing time out error when try to connect MS SQL Server that installed in azure Virtual machine.

error:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

But when I try to run the application in Visual studio editor(localhost and OS in windows) it is working.
earlier it was throwing network related issue after whitelisting the IP now I am getting the the above mentioned TIMEOUT error .

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    ///code
 }
```

also I tried to give min and max pool size and "Integrated Security=false",true sspi etc in connection string.

Comment: Does it happen immediately, or only after running for a period of time? Have you done a review of `new SqlConnection(connectionString)` usages in the code to ensure that they're all in `using` blocks?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks for the reply ,it happens after running for a period of time. yes I checked all the codes are inside 'using' blocks only.

Comment: please check this similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23731876/timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elapsed-prior-to-obtaining-a-connection-from)

Answer (score 0):

If you recall properly, the default value for the Max Pool Size is 100.
your code waited for a database connection, but the timeout (which you set) is expired. It depends on how long it takes for your queries to finish for a website. Try to set a higher value in your connection strings: ***Max Pool Size=200***

There was a network time out or ***the number of connections in the pool (which you set) was too low for the number of connections you were attempting may cause a timeout error***

*To fix this issue please check this below code:*

```cs
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
     connection.Open();
     someCall(connection);
}
```

***Alternatively***

```cs
var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

try
{
     connection.Open();
     someCall (connection);
}
finally
{
     connection.Close();                
}
```

Please check this similar [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670774/how-can-i-solve-a-connection-pool-problem-between-asp-net-and-sql-server) *credits by splattne*

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried the above mentioned changes . Also there is no other application or connection is there for the SQL DB(inside VM) i mean it is one on one.

Comment: please check this similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23731876/timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elapsed-prior-to-obtaining-a-connection-from)