# How to handle long-running operations with the Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Our team is developing a machine that will perform a physical process on a tray that holds vials of medical samples.  The physical process will take approximately 1.5 hours.  The tray and related vials are entities, loaded from a database using the Entity Framework.  As the process runs, the device will update values on the entities.  The changes may happen minutes or seconds apart.  At the end of certain steps, between 10 and 45 minutes apart, we want to save those entities back to the database, and keep going.

Is it acceptable to have an Entity Framework context open for 1.5 hours?  Can I make changes and save the entities multiple times during that time period using that context?  If not, what is the best way to handle this?

Some ideas so far:

- We could use the attach/detach capability.  This should allow us to make changes to the entities outside of the context, then create a new context and attach the entity when we want to save, then detach it to continue working.
- We could create a new context every time we want to change one of the entities.  But I don't think we want to save every time we make a change.
- We could copy the entities to business objects, and make the changes there.  Then when we want to save, we would open a context and copy the changes into the entities, and save.

Comment: Personally, I'd use option 3 because it would separate the data access from 'business' concerns - but that's subjective. Other question worth asking here, especially from the database perspective, is: how many rows could potentially be changed and what is the scope of those changes (e.g. how many columns change on average)?

Comment: The reason a DbContext typically has a short lifespan is because it's rather inexpensive to create it. By keeping a long-living context you will fill its ObjectContext with entities, causing gradually increasing lookup time. However if in your scenario there isn't much database interaction, this should be no problem. I would just create contexts when needed and attach the existing objects.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek The app is 2-tier right now, so yeah, it works with the entities directly.  Each "tray" is about 159  rows.  Database speed is concern at this point - even if it took several seconds to update that would be fine.  Time is dominated by the physical operations not the network or database.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Fortunately, the context would only be used to save those same objects back.  Good point though - if we need to pull something else, we must be sure to use a different context or risk getting stale data or eating memory.

Comment: @MobyDisk Then the main question is whether you want to persist the changes *at checkpoints* or only when the process is fully done. That was touched upon in some of the answers - failure recovery will also influence how you save the data to the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A combination of 2 and 3 will be ideal.

First off, do not keep a context open for hours at a time. You can do this through configuration but it is just going to waste resources considering that you are doing an operation for 90 minutes and it should take roughly 3 milliseconds to open a connection.

So just create a context as you need it. Next, keep in mind that although you open a context to gather data or maintain state, you do not actually need to save the data if it is not ready to be stored. You can just store it locally.

This is where step 3 comes in, with local memory. Basically you should keep it in local memory with an event handler attached. As the local copy changes, have the database update if the change has occurred within some acceptable time window.

Comment: `it is just going to waste resources` in a general sense yes, but if this is dedicated equipment for a specific research task, I would argue that it does not matter.  What is right for a high-volume website (or certainly 99% of database apps), isn't necessarily right here.

Comment: @EricJ. - I agree, it is a waste of resource in general. Clearly bypassing best practice based on project size is always going to be an option.

Comment: @EricJ. When you both say "waste resources" you seem to be referring to the database connection itself.  But if I am reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282675 properly, it does not keep the database connection open for the entire time.  As for load, there will be <5 of these machines running at one time connected to the database.  And the database is dedicated to these devices and nothing else.

Comment: @MobyDisk - Every time the database connection is open a connection thread is consumed. The thread will not be released until the connection is closed (disposed). The connection isn't active the entire time, but the connection thread is still being held. This is why if you open a connection but do not dispose of it you will leak connection threads and lock your database out from being able to hand out new connections.

Comment: @TravisJ: Looks like the database connection is in fact not being held if you allow EF to manage opening/closing the connection (which is news to me).

Comment: I don't actually know what we will ultimately do, but I wanted to accept someones answer since everyone helped.  Using separate business objects may help with a multi-threading issue as well.  In some cases, we hand off parts of the tray to different "robots" and do some work in parallel.  So I might need those objects anyway.

Comment: @MobyDisk - Feel free to [come chat in the c# chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c) if you would like to get some feedback on design in a less strict environment than asking on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it acceptable to have an Entity Framework context open for 1.5 hours?

UPDATE: Per the resources you link, if you allow EF to manage the opening and closing of the connection, it will open the connection as late as possible and close it as early as possible, so that the relatively costly database connection can be returned to the connection pool.  The connection will only be held open for the duration that the context exists if you manually manage the database connection.

> At the end of certain steps, between 10 and 45 minutes apart, we want to save those entities back to the database, and keep going.

Note that if the client crashes for any reason, the changes kept in memory will be lost.  Consider the impact of this when deciding whether you really want to wait that long before persisting your data.

If it is quite certain that this is and will remain an architecture with one or just a few clients writing to a dedicated database, I would opt to keep the code as simple as possible... trading resource inefficiency that does not matter in this very specific case for a lesser chance of programmer error.

Comment: If I am reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282675/ properly, it does not keep the database connection open for the entire time.

Comment: That's interesting... I did not realize that the connection is automatically closed if it was automatically opened.  All the more reason to go with the simplest version in terms of coding.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111594/why-always-close-database-connection to further confirm your reading.

Comment: Yeah, that makes this the simplest approach.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to save data in batches and that it's no use to save individual values if a batch as a whole doesn't succeed.

Since resources are not the bottleneck and this is a dedicated system, it doesn't matter that a context lives relatively long, so I would use a context per batch. The context collects the data and concludes each batch by one `SaveChanges` call, which automatically saves one batch in one database transaction. Roughly, the code would look like this:

```
do
{
    // Start of a new batch.
    using(var db = new MyContext())
    {
        // Collect data into the context
        ...
        SaveChanges();
    }
} while (....); // While there are new batches
```

Database connections will be opened and closed when needed. `SaveChanges` will do this, but also any other database interaction you may need in-between. EF will never leave a connection open for longer than necessary.